# adapter.Fill(ds) not acceptable in visual studio

Tags: vb.net, dataset

I have written following code to create DataSet:

```
    Dim connectionString As String = "********"
    Dim conn As New SqlConnection(connectionString)
    conn.Open()

    Try
        Dim cmd As SqlCommand = conn.CreateCommand
        cmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM TABCODE WHERE TABCODE_FUNNUM='AAAREN02'"
        Dim adp As SqlDataAdapter = New SqlDataAdapter(cmd)
        Dim ds As DataSet = New DataSet

        adp.Fill(ds)

    Catch ex As Exception

    End Try
```

In this, the last line adp.Fill(ds) in VS2015 is highlighted as an error with :

> Overload resolution failed because no accessible 'Fill' can be called with these arguments

What am I doing wrong???

I have also imported the followings:

```
Imports System
Imports System.Data
Imports System.Data.SqlClient
```

Comment: What does it say when you hover over it?

Comment: Overload resolution failed because no accessible 'Fill' can be called with these arguments

Comment: Does it compile?  It could just be an IDE bug... the code itself looks fine.

Comment: Did you create your own class called DataSet?

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: Originally thought I had found a syntax error. Changed to use a different Overload for `Fill`

```
Dim ds As DataSet = New DataSet()
adp.Fill(ds, "TabCodes")
```

Comment: VB.NET is not strict like C# - it is acceptable to omit the parens on method invocations.

Comment: Interesting.  Most examples that I have seen include giving a name.  `Dim ds As Dataset = New DataSet("CodesDataSet")`

Comment: The parameterless constructor assigns a default name of `"NewDataSet"`.  Even the MSDN example documentation omits the parentheses when calling the parameterless constructor : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zfd6zwtd%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: Good to know (although, yes, I primarily use C#)  :).  I've been looking at examples that included the data adapter because I haven't used those in years.  When I did it was common to specify names.

Answer (score -1):

Try this.

```
Using connection As New SqlConnection(connectionString)
    Dim adp As New SqlDataAdapter()
    Dim dSet as Dataset = New DataSet()
    adp.SelectCommand = New SqlCommand(queryString, connection)
    adp.Fill(dSet)
End Using
```

Comment: Why should he try this?  What is the problem with the original code and how does this solve it?

Comment: whoops just noticed I forgot to declare dataSet ... Other than that though he should be using "Using" when opening SQL connections - this code snippet is better and more concise code than what he originally posted.

Comment: I still don't see how this answers the question.

Comment: @Nefarii   In addition to not declaring the DataSet, what about `queryString` in `adp.SelectCommand = New SqlCommand(queryString, connection)`

Comment: Really? he needs help knowing what his connection and query strings are? that's honestly just unnecessary knit picking. Ill give you the DataSet but everything else is self explanatory (and adds unnecessary clutter)  AND I even included advice on how to improve his code.

Comment: I wasn't trying to knit pick.  I pointed that out because of the comment that the code was "more concise".